# Button header in reopen queue does not scroll horizontally

Tags: bug

This was my initial view in the reopen queue. The Skip button was out of view:

[image]

When I scrolled all the way to the right, the top bar stayed in place and the button still was not visible:

[image]

FireFox 63.0.1 Under Win7 64. My monitor text size is set to 'Normal' 125%.

This seems to be system wide, I just noticed in the First Post review queue on [EarthScience.SE] sa well.